# How to use Laravel 5 HTML Purifier on $request object?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, htmlpurifier

I am using [HTMLPurifier for Laravel 5](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) package for cleaning my input field. Currently my `store()` method is like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Some business logic goes here

    $post = Post::create($request->all());

    // More business logic
}
```

and my `$request` variable contains these:

```
{
  "_token": "zbyUnJuAbSliem40B6xjWJfGOayoFlRSVIvrDlDM",
  "title": "Test Title",
  "slug": "test-title",
  "category_id": "1",
  "tags": [
    "2"
  ],
  "body": "<p>Test body.</p>"
}
```

How can I use `Purifier::clean()` method on `$request` variable only to purify the `$request->body` element?

If I use `Purifier::clean($request->all())` then it add `<p>` tag to all of the elements of `$request` object rather then only `body` element like this:

```
{
  "_token": "<p>zbyUnJuAbSliem40B6xjWJfGOayoFlRSVIvrDlDM</p>",
  "title": "<p>Test Title</p>",
  "slug": "<p>test-title</p>",
  "category_id": "<p>1</p>",
  "tags": [
    "<p>2</p>"
  ],
  "body": "<p>Test body.</p>"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the answer, it can be done by the following way:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Some business logic goes here

    $request->merge(['body' => Purifier::clean($request->get('body'))]);
    $post = Post::create($request->all());

    // More business logic
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your `Post` model, you can do the following...

```
public function setBodyAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['body'] = Purifier::clean($value);
}
```

This way you don't have to do the same logic over and over any time you create a new post.

Comment: hi will your approach work when mass filling attributes and not manually assigning them? Perhaps laravel does not call $model->body = $request->body when doing mass assign and your method would not work?

Comment: You asked a while ago, but if some come here, this will work with mass assignment too. Just tested on L 5.6. Only thing I would change in this answer is to use `$value` instead of `request()->body`. Personally, I don't like to use requests in model.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `merge` method on the request:

```
$request->merge(['body' => Purifier::clean($request->get('body')]);
```

**Edit**

I meant to use `->merge` and not `->replace` in the above.

Comment: Your method will remove all attributes of `$request` object except just `$request->body`. Check my answer, I think it would be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one :

```
Purifier::clean($request->get('body'));
```